# Can I use pdf.js viewer just from the CDN?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I have a PHP project, a simple one-page with some pdf files to watch/download.
I downloaded their prebuilt stable v2.8.335, and with this I can access to the original pdf viewer (folder web/viewer.html).

But, it will be a lot better for me if I can use their CDN instead of adding the files to my project.

Can I access to the original pdf viewer with only the CDN ?

If yes, how can I do that? In the documentation I only found how to customise my own, but that's not what I want.

Thank you for your time, I hope my question isn't to stupid..

Comment: I'd prefer to use the CDN so I won't have to add files to my project. But if I have no choice I'll add the folders.

Correct my if I'm wrong, but it's like for bootstrap, if you want to theme it you'll have to add the folder etc.. but lot of bootstrap function can be use with the CDN.

So I wanted to use the CDN to access to the original viewer, but if there is no other way I'll add the folder.